# A question about factor ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I am learning abstract algebra now. I am confused that why $\mathbb{Z}_4/2 \mathbb{Z}_4=\{[0+4\mathbb{Z}],[1+4\mathbb{Z}]\}$.

$2 \mathbb{Z}_4=\{0+4\mathbb{Z},2+4\mathbb{Z}\}$, $\mathbb{Z_4}=\{0+4\mathbb{Z},1+4\mathbb{Z},2+4\mathbb{Z},3+4\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Why $\mathbb{Z}_4/2 \mathbb{Z}_4\ne\{[0+4\mathbb{Z}],[1+4\mathbb{Z}]\,[2+4\mathbb{Z}],[3+4\mathbb{Z}]\}$?

How to get $\mathbb{Z}_4/2 \mathbb{Z}_4=\{[0+4\mathbb{Z}],[1+4\mathbb{Z}]\}$?

Comment: HINT: Are $[0+4\mathbb{Z}]$ and $[2+4\mathbb{Z}]$ actually different things?

Comment: @NoahSchweber $[0+\mathbb{4Z}]$ mod $4=0$,$[2+\mathbb{4Z}]$ mod $4=2$ They are the same?

Comment: Do you even know the definition of quotient rings?

Answer (score 2):

I'll denote $\mathbb{Z_4} = \{\bar0,\bar1,\bar2,\bar3\}$ so $2\mathbb{Z_4} = \{ \bar0, \bar2 \}$. Take an element $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4/2 \mathbb{Z}_4$ this element has the form $\bar a + 2\mathbb{Z_4}$ for some $\bar a \in \mathbb{Z_4}$, remember that two elements $a ,b \in \mathbb{Z}_4/2 \mathbb{Z}_4$ are "the same" if $\bar a - \bar b \in 2\mathbb{Z_4}$.

Consider $\bar 3, \bar 1 \in \mathbb{Z_4}$ since $\bar 3 - \bar 1 = \bar 2 \in 2\mathbb{Z_4}$ then $ 3 $ and $1$ are the same in the quotient space. You can do similar calculations to see that the only classes in $\mathbb{Z}_4/2 \mathbb{Z}_4$  are the ones of $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Why $a,b$ are the same if $a-b\in 2\mathbb{Z_4}$?

Comment: $a,b$ are the same in the quotient ring if $\bar a - \bar b \in 2\mathbb{Z_4}$ following the notation i used in the answer. Is just part of the definition of quotient ring. (See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuotientRing.html))